# Display timestamp on edited comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits

When a comment is edited, a writing utensil icon is appended to the comment. On hover, the alternative text displays: `this comment was edited`.

I think, that in some cases, it would be helpful to include a timestamp to this copy.

For example:

`this comment was edited at 2012-11-21 02:37:43Z` or the `@` symbol in place of `at`.
Another possibility is to make it similar to edits, where `edited X minutes ago` is used.

Answer (score 4):

Given that all edits to a comment need to happen within the 5 minute window after its initial creation, is that really necessary? I'm just not sure what kinds of problems not knowing the precise edit time of a comment causes that this would solve?

Comment: Completely agree +1

Comment: If it was edited after someone else happened to comment within the 5 minute window. Given there is no revision history for comments, some people will likely wonder what the original comment was that they replied to. A timer to see if they indeed did change their comment after you posted yours (or while constructing it) seems like a simple next-best feature. Considering the suggestion is to put this info in a hover based box, and I can't imagine that the extra server time to serve up this info in the HTML would be substantial, can't see the downside for the UI or performance of the system.

Comment: "*If it was edited after someone else happened to comment within the 5 minute window*" That would only be moderators, and I doubt they edit other people's comments enough to warrant this feature either. Like nearly all comment feature requests, it's both pointless and futile!